# This is not a question, but an interesting thing I discovered yesterday in visual studio c++ 17 compiler

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, c++17

```
int* func() {
    int c = 5;
    return &c;
}

int main() {
    int* s = func();
    std::cout << *(s) << "\n";
    *(s) = 1000;
    std::cout << *(s);
}
```

On my visual studio compiler this code works fine and giving me 5 and 1000. And I also checked it with 3 variables and discovered, that function keeps only one variable in memory for the lifetime of all program. So if anyone interested please check this code on your visual studio c++ 17 compiler. I just interested is it my compiler doesnt work fine or this is typical problem. Also in another compiler this code returns error as it must be.

Comment: *"Also in another compiler this code returns error as it must be"* - No, that's not as it must be. The behavior is undefined, which means anything can be done for that construct. If it was *defined* to be an error, we'd all be having an easier time.

Comment: I am new co c++ so I thought this might be strange thing, so I shared it to understand it a bit more. So thanks for this information. I appreciate that. And yes this answers my question. Thank you.